# Favicon 404 error on Heroku Django deployment

Tags: django, heroku, amazon-s3

I'm using S3 for static files for my Django Heroku app. All the files show up fine, except the favicon (even after updating my cache). The favicon works locally, but it does not show up on my heroku app. Additionally, Django sends me the following error:

```
[Django] ERROR (EXTERNAL IP): Internal Server Error: /favicon.ico
```

My favicon link in my base template is:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{STATIC_URL}}/images/icons/favicon.ico?v=2">
```

Is there something special I need to do for this file, but not other static files? I've looked around here for answers, but nothing has helped me thus far.

Answer (score 2):

The request for `/favicon.ico` is being caused by the [default behaviour of some web browsers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon#Limitations_and_criticism) who just assume that the favicon will be present at `/favicon.ico`.

You could add a 301 redirect to the actual favicon path.

Can you do something like this in your `urls.py` file?

`(r'^favicon\.ico$', 'django.views.generic.simple.redirect_to', {'url': '/static/images/favicon.ico'}),`

See http://www.codekoala.com/posts/setup-faviconico-django/

Comment: definitely worth trying, but it didn't work. I even hard-coded my aws s3 path into the url redirect, but that didn't work. The only way I can get it work is to hard code the s3 path in my base_template: `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://my_bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/images/icons/favicon.ico">`

Comment: Weird, I don't know Django, but at least you got something working :)

Comment: That `urls.py` code won't work with recent versions of Django.

Comment: for more on the code above, see this article and the comments: http://www.apreche.net/django-favicon-with-amazon-s3/comment-page-1/#comment-59303